# How Can I Know In Which Component I Was There

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuedraggable

I am working with vue js, and I have dargable component items, I generated dragable component using for loop to display component, so how can i detected in which component I am there, when click on component.

This is my index.vue file :

```
import item from './component/itemComponent.vue'; 
<template>
  <div>
    <dragable
      :element="ul"
      v-modal="list">
       <li v-for="(index, i) in list" :key="i">
           <item :indexItem="index"></item
       </li>
    </dragable>
  </div>
</template>
```

And this is itemComponent.vue file :

```
<template>
    <a 
       @click="getComponentAttributes()" 
       class="btn btn-primary">{{ intemIndex.name }} </a>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
   props:['indexItem'],
   data(){
      return {
         isOpen: false
     }
   },
   methods : {
    getComponentAttributes(){
             this.isOpen = true; 
                // its not working just for one 
               // component, it working for all component and  I need 
              //  to implment to one component specific 
             // current component
       }
  } 
}
</script>
```

Comment: You can extend and override those methods or even pass them as property ? Not sure what you want actually.

Comment: @Estradiaz i need to access to attribute  "isOpen" for every component, and change "isOpen" for each one separately.

Comment: @Estradiaz no, it's working correctly, and every component has "isOpen" is false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited following comments.

A bit complicated but does the trick. https://jsfiddle.net/guillaumedeslandes/t12k43ov/

Added events to trigger a forced-close state, and had to store the item state in the parent component to allow `draggable` to manipulate it while keeping the order.

Comment: it's doesn't make any things @guillaume.deslandes

Comment: Not exactly your code, but the `isOpen` status works in this fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/guillaumedeslandes/t12k43ov/1/

Comment: cooool, until this stage is okay, so what i need is when i drag item, other open items should be false @guillaume.deslandes

Comment: A bit messy but this one adds a prop to close all while dragging, and restores status on drag end. https://jsfiddle.net/guillaumedeslandes/t12k43ov/8/

Comment: thank you so much for your consideration, it's seems you have reached the solution, but i think your solution its complicated a little bit for me, i mean if you have any way to explain it more i will be thankful to you so much.
this code the logic is not clear enough
`computed: {
   isOpen() {
     return this.item.toggled && !this.forceClose;
    },
  },
  methods: {
    toggle() {
      this.item.toggled = !this.item.toggled;
    },
  },
`

Comment: how about if we make it, if user click instead of when dragging, does do the trick ? or make anythings !
when user click open current item be `isOpen = true` and other open items should be `isOpen = flase `

Comment: The `toggle` method, is there to change to open status each time the item is clicked. The `isOpen` was added to handle the dragging behaviour you mentioned in your comment (when i drag item, other open items should be false). The item is "really" open if its status is `toggled == true` and if it is not required to be closed for another reason (`forceClose`).

Comment: it's perfect , Thank you so much @guillaume.deslandes, this issue taking for me more than two weeks. and now you save my day.

Comment: Hi, @guillaume.deslandes I wonder what if i need, when click on item open current item `isOpen = true` and other open items should be close, instead of when drag.. is this possible ?

Comment: Updated the fiddle. I added a `clicked` event emitted when an item is opened. I is caught by the parent, closing all items but this one. If you also want to close other items when dragging, change `onStart` by `onStartWithClose`.

Comment: a great solution @guillaume.deslandes, and I appreciated your effort to help me thank so much :)...
but i think my parent component `clicked` not worked, just child component her `clicked` worked, i don't know what is problem, but i am working on...

you are open my mind and extended, thanks again bro..